# How to avoid special character encoding in view?

Tags: php, knockout.js, zend-framework2

I'm using Zend Framework 2 along with Knockout js  and I have a form that have knockout binding field like this.

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'TenTaikhoan',
        'type' => 'Text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => '', //TenTaikhoan
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'data-bind' => 'value: $root.taikhoan.TenTaikhoan' //Here
        ),
    ));
```

But when I render in view it show like this result in failing to bind.

```
<input type="text" name="TenTaikhoan" class="form-control" data-bind="value&#x3A;&#x20;&#x24;root.taikhoan.TenTaikhoan" value="TestTest">
```

So, is there any way I can render a view without encoding special character?

Thanks

Comment: Try ko.observable('value: $root.taikhoan.TenTaikhoan')

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can make the page charset to utf-8.
Also you can use the Escaper class of zend framework. Refer this link
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.escaping-html.html